# Date Range Picker disable date issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

How to disable a date I want to disable **20 December 2018**, but code below is not working.

where am I wrong?

```
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()),
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
           if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2018-12-20') {
                return true; 
           }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work well (after changing `minDate` :)?

See below snippet

```js
$(function(){
   $('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        minDate: new Date(),
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2018-12-20') {
                return true; 
            }
        }
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.js"></script>


<input id="datepicker" >
```

Comment: I found the true issue, because my daterangepicker version is 1.3.2, minDate: new Date() wont work on that version, now I change to version 3.0.3, and your code is working, thx alot.

Comment: @vbnewbie  , Glad that you find the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()),
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
        var dateParsed = $.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', date);
        if (dateParsed === '2018-12-20') {
            return false; 
        }
    }
});
```

I went through the docs briefly so give it a shot.

Comment: Im using this plugin http://www.daterangepicker.com/, not JQuery DatePicker

Comment: Seem like plugin version issue, anyway still thx for your help